# Which ubuntu server iso version could support "Try Ubuntu"?

Tags: server, ssh, reboot

I'm trying to search an ubuntu server version and don't care the version, but it should support "Try Ubuntu".  I have downloaded some ubuntu server iso image, all of them could not support "Try Ubuntu", but I don't want to execute any options about "Install Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu .....".
   At the same time, I also tried ubuntu desktop versions, they could support "Try Ubuntu", but after "Try Ubuntu", there is not any ssh server has been started. I need to start ssh server and as far as I know, ubuntu server version could offer ssh server service.So I'm trying to search ubuntu server version.
   Is there such an ubuntu server iso image?

Comment: There is a 'live' server option; so it'd be closest to what I think you want, but along with @Nmath it sounds like you want a GUI to me (where GUI uses resources & doesn't make sense for efficient servers)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-live-server.html.en

Comment: @Nmath@guiverc It doesn't matter whether there is any GUI. My really purpose are :1. Just "Try Ubuntu", don't "Install Ubuntu", don't care by command or GUI, in fact I will make an automatic ISO instead of any interactions 2. After "Try Ubuntu" finished, I also need a ssh server has been started in the host.

Comment: @guiverc I have tried ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso, it could install a ssh server, but there is no any option about "Try Ubuntu' and I must run "Install Ubuntu".

Answer (score 2):

There's an `Enter shell` button in `Help` menu at top-right of screen when I booting the Ubuntu22.04 Server ISO. Although I don't know why they hide this button in a tiny inconspicuous `Help` menu.

From that shell I can install almost packages with `apt` and play with them without issue. But note that any change won't survive rebooting.

There's also a `Help on SSH access` in menu. It gives the user and password(and key) with which you can login via SSH. You can also create your own user in shell.